# CastError while making a put request for a user in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, api, express

I am making a post request on the API endpoint `http://localhost:5000/api/notes/updatenote:id` where **id** is an `id of a particular user`. The API just simply updates the notes associated with the user where `notes` is itself a MongoDB collection with their own id. I am trying to make the PUT request but I am getting this error. I had made a lot of commit for an easy understanding of the code, but in case of any doubt, you can ask me for more information.

**Error**

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":61473ebd4ce15cca37954d28" (type string) at path "_id" for model "notes"
```

**code for PUT**

```
//ROUTE 3 :Update notes of a particular user PUT:/api/notes/updatenote:id

router.put("/updatenote:id", fetchUser, async (req, res) => {
  console.log("put request starts");

  const { updatedTitle, updatedDescription, updatedTag } = req.body;
  //console.log(req.body);

  //Create a newNote object
  let newNote = {};
  if (updatedTitle) {
    newNote.title = updatedTitle;
  }
  if (updatedDescription) {
    newNote.description = updatedDescription;
  }
  if (updatedTag) {
    newNote.tag = updatedTag;
  }

  console.log("param val - "+req.params.id)

  //finding the note to be updated and update it
  let noteToBeUpdated = await Notes.findById(req.params.id); //id in the parameter
  console.log(noteToBeUpdated);

  if (!noteToBeUpdated) {
    return res.status(404).send("Not found");
  }

  //req.user.id == person ki id who is updating and notetobeupdated.user = jiska note update ho rha uski id
  if (noteToBeUpdated.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
    return res.status(401).send("Unauthorised User");
  }

  noteToBeUpdated = await Notes.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $set: newNote },
    { new: true }
  );

  res.json({ noteToBeUpdated });

});
```

**Request body**

```
{
   "title":"First song (debut)",
   "description":"First Debut song in launched in 2015.",
   "tag":"music"
}
```

**notes collection**

```
[    {
    "_id": "61473ebd4ce15cca37954d28",
    "user": "61432ac5225cd230999f178d",
    "title": "First song",
    "description": "First song in English language worldwide.",
    "tag": "science",
    "date": "2021-09-19T13:44:29.386Z",
    "__v": 0
    }
]
```

**Full log of Error**[image]

Answer (score 1):

your string `_id` contains `:` and mongoose could convert this string to objected
change `router.put("/updatenote:id"` to `router.put("/updatenote/:id"`

Comment: I am making wrong request on postman !!!

Comment: could you provide postman exmaple  ?

Comment: I HAVE CORRECTED IT